# Extend Property of existing type into another nested type

Tags: typescript

The title explains it all.

No, I am kidding, I couldn't have picked up a worse title.

I have a `DefaultTheme` interface

```
  export interface DefaultTheme {
    colors: {
      background: '#fff'
      text: '#1d1d1f'
      secondaryText: '#515154'
      primary: '#06c'
    }
    pages: PageTheme
  }
```

And then I want to extend with `PageTheme` for specific pages, `PageTheme` looks like this:

```
  export interface PageTheme {
    sensei: {
      colors: {
        background: '#fff'
        text: '#1d1d1f'
        secondaryText: '#515154'
        background: '#06090D' //different
      }
    }
  }
```

And here my problem lies, I dont need everything from `DefaultTheme`, I only need to extend the `colors` in this case, so that I just retype the `backgroundColor`

So what I have tried is:

```
 export interface PageTheme {
    sensei: {
      colors: DefaultTheme & {
        background: '#06090D'
      }
    }
  }
```

And then I try to combine the colors into the actual objects:

```
const defaultTheme: Omit<DefaultTheme, 'pages'> = {
  colors: {
    background: '#fff',
    text: '#1d1d1f',
    secondaryText: '#515154',
    primary: '#06c',
  },
}

const pagesThemes: PageTheme = {
  sensei: {
    colors: {
      ...defaultTheme.colors,
      background: '#06090D',  // this gives me an error "Type string is not assignable to type 'never'."
    },
  },
}
```

Redefining the background color for `pagesThemes.sensei.colors.background` gives me `Type string is not assignable to type 'never'.` this error

Basically all I want to do is spread my default values, and just redefine the ones that are different.

Comment: Are you sure you really want color constants to be part of a type and not only values?

Comment: Yep, I want to get alarmed should any value ever be changed by mistake. Its not something that gets changed every day, so these files will rarely be revisited.

Answer (score 0):

It's very unlikely that you really want colors to be a part of the type, but if you really need it and you know hat you are doing, here are 2 ways:

1. [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgEWCwFcAbGAFQAtgBbPAbwFgAoOObCU6AZwC44zNuzgAjHAGsA5lAjEkAEwEByAMToNy1iLioQMFaoCMCk0fRbh7HsE6LMUAJ4VQBuGoCsRrx4AslnTAoBFoHR0MABgA2bAC4AF9tODBMKWB+OAAFVOBqOmBWRJZtUEhYRBQ0LFwsnLz6QSSbJBsEASEdTm4oDIB5WgQYAB5CEnJ64AAaOAAicWxpWXkFGYA+OAAyRqsRecW5RUioiIBOCPw49iKrwtZWBVtSBzw7HngALwFstInWd4A6Zqtf5dXj-PYyA4KOAAehhs1U0VO5xmQA)

```
export interface DefaultTheme {
  colors: {
    background: '#fff'
    text: '#1d1d1f'
    secondaryText: '#515154'
    primary: '#06c'
  }
  pages: PageTheme
}

 export interface PageTheme {
  sensei: {
    colors: Omit<DefaultTheme, "background"> & {
      background: '#06090D'
    }
  }
}

declare const z: PageTheme
z.sensei.colors.background // "#06090D"
```

2. [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsA26oGcA8AQgOLIQAekIAJrsrmFKAOYB8yA3gLABQyyAI0QBrZlHQBXGgC5kJADS9+kSrIDkAYgCM1HVphql9CAnQ04UAJ4AVCmHUaArFueOALIb7IADkwC2FpYOAAwAbAieAL68vBTeOGDIoJCwiCgAIhDwEphg1gAWEH4o3F6m2HiyGBUEmjD1aqxG3nDMELiyAAqtEAVFELzRPLHk8VCJydDwSMjdbX3FnEa4ECArwLKl-PzlOB1oWHv4mmHBAJzB6Y1GQ0O81CaYFiima4kAXl09CwM87wB0KzWEGA-12eH+QgQonEUmoyAA9AjkAAiDSnC7pFFAA)

```
interface Colors<BG extends string> {
  background: BG,
  text: '#1d1d1f'
  secondaryText: '#515154'
  primary: '#06c'
}

export interface DefaultTheme {
  colors: Colors<'#fff'>
  pages: PageTheme
}

export interface PageTheme {
  sensei: {
    colors: Colors<'#06090D'>
  }
}

declare const z: PageTheme
z.sensei.colors.background // "#06090D"
```

3. Use helper type: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gbhAToglgEwgHgCoBooCqAfFALxQDeAsAFBRQDaA1hCFCgHZQsgD2AZlGxQAPt1YDCAXQBc4thAAewCBzQBneZIJQA-IWaspUOdkNsAZFsHYpAbloBfWrSVheiYOw4rE-AIYAxtAAIhABAK4ANsDYABYQALbQ1HRQgbxRHupyqfT0AEZBTADmiLwRanIA5ADE-A3VtPlQKso1tQCMaN2d-E1p9OoQGWr+iCDYSsAdAKyd87MALAMtYKiJ4yAdAAwAbIGrUM5pYP4lEDlQAArnEPFJEE4udG4eXpy+AcE3dw-JlGaUGGHGGKFyQPoGSyiCu8CQqAwmDCkRi-wg+DyLSgRUCpXKlTQuz2OwAnDsQkd6I4iECTidaBhAlFxtBRuovAAvOS3C7o2icgB0ILBguh2UFuPxFTUUAA9HKoAAiWr7MkUpVAA)

```
type Override<T, U> = {
  [key in keyof T | keyof U]: key extends keyof U ? U[key] : T[key & keyof T];
}

export interface DefaultTheme {
  colors: {
    background: '#fff'
    text: '#1d1d1f'
    secondaryText: '#515154'
    primary: '#06c'
  }
  pages: PageTheme
}

 export interface PageTheme {
  sensei: {
    colors: Override<DefaultTheme, {
      background: '#06090D'
    }>
  }
}

declare const z: PageTheme
z.sensei.colors.background // "#06090D"
```

Comment: Thanks! It solves the issue, but not in the way that I want it to solve it, I just want to be able to override colors just by typing the new value for the color, Omit requires an extra step to add the color in the Omitted colors, while the `Colors` example is specific to the background. It should beflexible, as it is with normal objects. If we talk in `object` and `js` terms, I simply want to "spread the color types" and redefine the new ones, just like I did with the actual object themselves, I want to replicate that behavior in the type, without Omit

Comment: @Darkbound, then use helper type. Added 3rd way.